# Why is $\ln\frac{1}{x}=-\ln x$?

Tags: logarithms

I have just discovered this property of the natural logarithm, but why is this statement true? What is the proof that $\ln(1/x)=-\ln(x)$?

Comment: It depends---how are you defining the logarithm?

Comment: Isn't this true for every value of x?

Comment: No, $x$ has to be positive (assuming complex numbers are not in the game)

Comment: What is your definition of the logarithm?  Is it a real function?  complex function?  Is it defined as the inverse of the exponential?  as the integral of a hyperbola?  by a power series?

Comment: Okay thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: There are many proofs out there, but as Xander mentions, how do you define the $ln$? Personally, I think that introducing the $ln$ as an integral is a clean approach upon which your question can be very easily answered.

Comment: And why can you say that if $e^a= e^b$ then necessarily $a=b$?

Comment: Right, because a baby learning to say "Mama" has to be told that some cultures will distinguish cousinhood based an whether the sibling parents are the same gender or not and the baby most specify which culture it is in before we answer the question...  $\ln x = k$ means that $e^k = x$ (and it is assumed such a pair of x,k are distinct).  So as $e^{-k} = \frac 1{e^k}$ if $x = e^k$ then $e^{-k} = \frac 1x$ so $\ln \frac 1x = -k = -\ln x$.  That's it.  There's some complication with complex numbers, and there's some complications with what the definition of $e$ is but... let's not worry yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition

$$y= \ln x \iff e^y=x$$

then

$$y= -\ln x \iff -y= \ln x\iff e^{-y}=x\iff e^y=\frac1x\iff y=\ln \frac1x$$

that is

$$y= -\ln x \iff y=\ln \frac1x$$

therefore

$$-\ln x =\ln \frac1x$$

Comment: Thanks Mark I really think that all solution given here are of high quality, your way is especially elegant to me!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

Begin with the integral definition of the logarithm function

$$\log(x)\equiv \int_1^x \frac1t\,dt \tag1$$

for $x>0$.

Enforce the substitution $t\mapsto 1/t$ to find

$$\log(x)=-\int_1^{1/x}\frac1t\,dt\tag2$$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we find that

$$\log(x)=-\log(1/x)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: This is like killing mosquitos with shotguns, don't you think?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout: why would the definition be a "shotgun"?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout No, I think that it is quite straightforward and elementary.

Comment: No, it is the proper way if the $\log(x)$ is defined the way you can see in the first equation.

Comment: Why does a minus appear of nowhere when you enforce the substitution t->1/t? And why did you use t instead of x ?

Comment: Very nice derivation!

Comment: When we substitute $t\mapsto 1/t$, we have $dt\mapsto -\frac1{t^2}$.  That is the source of the minus sign.  And $t$ is a dummy integration variable, while $x$ is an integration limit and fixed.

Comment: @gimusi Thank you very much.  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

Raise $e$ to the power of $\ln(1/x)$ and to the power of $-\ln x$. See that you get $\frac1x$ either way, and conclude that the numbers must've been equal to begin with (assuming you've already proven that the exponential function is injective).

Comment: Not a proof:  $e^a=e^b$ does not automatically imply that  $a=b$

Comment: @MarkFischler I've pointed that out, so I don't see how I've deserved a downvote.

Comment: +1 And actually the existence of an inverse $\ln$ allready indicates that the exponential function is injective.

Comment: @drhab We have a square root even though squaring isn't injective, so not really, no.

Comment: A square root is IMHO an inverse of the function $x\mapsto x^2$ with domain $[0,\infty)$ and codomain $[0,\infty)$ (which is injective).

Comment: @drhab But there are restrictions on the domain: logarithms are only defined on $(0,\infty)$, so it's even more restricted than the square root. To prove that it really is a full inverse, you can't just say that it is so "because it exists" because that's circular. You can't get away from some kind of proof of the injectivity of $x\mapsto e^x$. Either through calculus and a strictly positive derivative, or injectivity on the rationals plus continuity, or something else.

Comment: But is anything wrong with stating that: $\ln:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ serves as inverse of $\exp:\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ hence both functions are injective?

Comment: @drhab Not until you've proven that $\exp$ is really injective. Until then that statement is nonsense.

Comment: My answer on the question tells you what I actually had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=e^a$ then $a$ is called "$\ln(x)$", *the natural log of x*. Notice that $$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{e^a}=e^{-a}$$ So $-a=\ln(\frac{1}{x})$ also $-a=-\ln\left (x\right)$. Therefore $\ln\left (\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends deeply on your definition of the logarithm function.  Here are two possibilities.

> *Definition:*  Let $\exp(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$ denote the exponential function.  The exponential function is injective (this requires proof), thus it has a well-defined inverse with domain $(0,\infty)$.  Define the *natural logarithm* to be this inverse function.  That is, the logarithm is defined by the property that if $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\in (0,\infty)$ and $\exp(a) = b$, then
>   $$ \log(b) := a. $$

Under this definition,
\begin{align} \log\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = y
&\iff \mathrm{e}^y = \frac{1}{x} && \text{(defn of $\log$)} \\
&\iff \mathrm{e}^{-y} = x && \text{(properties of $\exp$)} \\
&\iff -y = \log(x) && \text{(defn of $\log$)} \\
&\iff y = -\log(x). && \text{(algebra)}
\end{align}
We therefore have
$$ \log\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = y = -\log(x), $$
which gives the desired result (via the transitivity of equality).

---

> *Definition:* For $x > 0$, define the *logarithm* by
>   $$ \log(x) := \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t. $$

By definition, we have
\begin{align}
\log\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)
&= \int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align}
We now want to make the change of variables $u = \frac{1}{t}$.  Using the usual computational tricks, we apply the power rule to get
$$ \frac{d}u = -\frac{1}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t = -u^2\,\mathrm{d}t
\implies \mathrm{d}t = -\frac{1}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u. $$
Also, when $t = 1$ we have $u=1$, and when $t=\frac{1}{x}$ we have $u = x$ (this deals with the limits of integration).  Hence
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t
&= -\int_{1}^{x} u \cdot \frac{1}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= -\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= -\log(x).
\end{align}
Putting this all together, we get
$$ \log\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = -\log(x), $$
which is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that function $\exp:\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ is bijective or equivalently has an inverse.

In this answer it is preassumed that function $\ln$ is **defined** as this inverse.

Then for $x>0$ we find:$$\exp(\ln\frac1x)=\frac1x=\frac1{\exp(\ln x)}=\exp(\ln  x)^{-1}=\exp(-\ln x)$$
That observation is enough to conclude that: $$\ln\frac1x=-\ln x$$