# If you have a $-\log$ of a fraction, why does taking the reciprocal change the sign at the front?

Tags: logarithms

For example,$$-\ln\left(\frac{\ln\sqrt{...\sqrt{\pi}}}{\ln\pi}\right)$$ becomes $$\ln\left(\frac{\ln\pi}{\ln\sqrt{...\sqrt{\pi}}}\right)$$ if you take the reciprocal of the inside function. Is this just a rule to memorise?

Comment: It's the same exponent rule $$\log(a^b) = b\log a$$ with $b=-1$. Nothing "extra" to memorize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\ln\frac{1}{x}=-\ln x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678201/why-is-ln-frac1x-ln-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\log\left(a^b\right)=b\log(a)$$
for $a\gt0$.
So
$$\log\left(\frac xy\right)=\log\left(\left(\frac yx\right)^{-1}\right)=-\log\left(\frac yx\right)$$
This is why taking the reciprocal makes the $\log$ negative.

Comment: Ah I see. I was just confused because in the examples I searched up they only have fractions like $\frac{1}{x}$ which removes the fraction on the inside (to just $x$)

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\ln\left(\frac1a\right) =-\ln(a)$$

As a check: $$\ln\left(\frac1a\right) +\ln(a) = \ln\left(\frac1a\times a\right) =\ln(1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Define $\ln t = \int_1^t \mathrm d x/x$. Substituting $u = 1/x, \mathrm d u = -1/x^2 \ \mathrm d x$ gives:

$$\ln \left( \frac{1}{t} \right) = \int_1^{1/t} \frac{1}{x} \frac{\mathrm du}{-1/x^2} = \int_1^{1/t} u \frac{\mathrm du}{-u^2} = -\int_1^{1/t} \frac{\mathrm du}{u} = -\ln t.$$